# I need to identify non-alternating values from a matrix using a vectorized method

Tags: matlab, vectorization

So, I've got a 1D matrix of values in MATLAB that will contain the value either 11 or 12.

For example `n=[11,12,11,12,12,12,11,11];`

I want to pick out values based on the following rules:

- Any value of 11 must be preceeded by a 12
- Any value of 12 must be followed by an 11

The format of the output isn't important.  An array that highlights which don't conform to the above rules such as `n1=[0,1,1,0,0,1,1,0];` would do the trick.

How can I do this in a vectorized way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code should work:

```
n=[11,12,11,12,12,12,11,11];
nd = diff(n);
n1 = [0 nd]==-1 | [nd 0]==-1;
```

Basically we are looking at the sequence with preceding number is greater than following by 1.